# Get ID from array file_get_contents

Tags: parsing, file-get-contents

How to get ID's from array to get and put contents from urls. Need get data from url's and save it in folder. I'm new in PHP and try something like this, but it's don't work for me:

```
$array = array("10", "11", "12");
$contents = file_get_contents('http://www.example.cpm/id='.$array.'&type=text');
file_put_contents('folder/'.$array.'.html', $contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I done it, just using foreach() )))